# how to set text box value to null or text

Tags: c#

i am creating a report from SQL database and created RDLC report using query and want to filter the data with the text box. i want to search the data with the input text box value or need to see the entire result if the text box is empty for that i need to assign my text box to null in case of no input in the text box how can i do that.

```
 {
     this.TCARDHOLDERSTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.TCARDHOLDERS, Code.Text);

     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

i want to fill the `Code.text` or null

Comment: Write a conditional statement to insert a null value if Code.Text is blank/Empty. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-isnullorempty-method/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set empty textbox to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849148/how-to-set-empty-textbox-to-null)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the terniary operator like this:

```
this.TCARDHOLDERSTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.TCARDHOLDERS, Code.Text != String.Empty ? Code.Text : null );
```