# how to set empty textbox to null

Tags: c#

Hi I am creating a RDLC report and I have  text box for search criteria from the sql database so I want to set all empty textbox to null so that as per sql query the report will be generated

how can I do that

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FNAME, LNAME, ID, COMPANY, INVITER, LOCATION;
        FNAME = textBoxFname.Text;
        LNAME = textBoxLname.Text;
        ID = textBoxIqama.Text;
        COMPANY = textBoxCompany.Text;
        INVITER = textBoxInviter.Text;
        LOCATION = textBoxLocation.Text;
        { 
            if (textBoxFname.Text == "") 
            {
                FNAME = null;
            } 
          }  
            if (textBoxLname.Text == "") 
            {
                LNAME = null;
            }

            if (textBoxIqama.Text == "")
            {
                ID = null;
            }

            if (textBoxCompany.Text == "") 
            {
                COMPANY = null;
            }

            if (textBoxInviter.Text == "") 
            {
                INVITER = null;
            }

            if (textBoxLocation.Text == "") 
            {
                LOCATION = null;
            }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.visitorreportTableAdapter.Fill(this.Companysearch.visitorreport, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value, FNAME, LNAME, ID, COMPANY, INVITER, LOCATION);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: What UI framework is this?  It's not entirely clear what you're asking; what are you seeking to do different than the code you've provided?  When a `Text` property is empty you want to set it to `null` as well as the accompanying variable?  Or you're looking for a way to avoid the boilerplate `if` blocks?

Comment: Also, the variables in `button1_Click()` are local and, therefore, not the same variables passed to `Fill()` in `button2_Click()`.  Where are the variables used in `button2_Click()` defined?

Comment: One final comment: how does this differ from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408488/how-to-set-text-box-value-to-null-or-text), if at all?  I see that each question references different tables but, otherwise, they seem to be asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about other types of textboxes, but in Winforms, the `Text` property of a `TextBox` will never return `null`. Perhaps the easiest would be to write a helper function for this:

```
public static string GetTextNullIfEmpty(string input)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? null : input;
}
```

Then you can implement it like:

```
string FNAME = GetTextNullIfEmpty(textBoxFname.Text);
```

Additionally, the variables declared inside a method are scoped only to that method. Therefore you cannot access the `FNAME` variable declared in `button1_Click` from within `button2_Click`. One way to resolve this is to declare these variable as class fields instead, so that all methods within the class have access to them:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Declare FNAME at class level so all methods can access it
    private string FNAME;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign a value to FNAME
        FNAME = GetTextNullIfEmpty(textBoxFname.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something with FNAME here
    }
}
```